# Changing function type in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, types

I have a function which has this type by default :

```
func :: Integer -> (Integer,Integer) -> [[String]] -> ([Char],[Char],[Char],[Char]) -> (Integer,Integer)
```

But I want it to return (Int,Int)
When I wrote this :

```
func:: Integer -> (Integer,Integer) -> [[String]] -> ([Char],[Char],[Char],[Char]) -> (Int,Int)
```

I get this error : 
Main> :l play

```
ERROR "play.hs":64 - Type error in explicitly typed binding
*** Term           : func
*** Type           : Integer -> (Integer,Integer) -> [[String]] -> ([Char],[Char],[Char],[Char]) -> (Integer,Integer)
*** Does not match : Integer -> (Integer,Integer) -> [[String]] -> ([Char],[Char],[Char],[Char]) -> (Int,Int)
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: `Int` is not `Integer`. Haskell has no implicit conversion between numeric types.

Comment: @nymk Do you have any suggestion to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a new wrapper function to wrap `func`, then use the wrapper function instead.

```
func' :: Integer ->
         (Integer,Integer) ->
         [[String]] ->
         ([Char],[Char],[Char],[Char]) ->
         (Int,Int)
func' a b c d = (fromInteger x, fromInteger y) where
    (x, y) = func a b c d
```

Alternatively, you could insert the calls to `fromInteger` directly into `func`.

The issue here is that `Int` and `Integer` are different types, and the compiler does not convert between them implicitly --- you have to do so explicitly, hence the calls to `fromInteger`. `fromInteger` converts from `Integer` to any numeric type.